# How to override chrome input box border when clicked?

Tags: css, google-chrome

How can I avoid the border that chrome puts on an input box, which is a different color when the user clicks on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property to remove that:

```
input {
    outline:none;
}
```